# Passing value from one window to the another in android

Tags: android, pass-by-value

I want to show the value inserted by user in first window to the next window.
I am accepting the User weight & height in first window and I want to show it on the second screen as Your weight & Height.

I search a lot and even tried a code but in emulator m getting forcefully closed error.

First Activity :

```
public class BMI_Main extends Activity
{
  EditText BMI_weight;
  public String weight;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bmi_main);
    Button submit =(Button)findViewById(R.id.BMI_submit);
    BMI_weight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.BMI_EdTx_kg);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {
    weight = BMI_weight.getText().toString();
    // create a bundle
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    // add data to bundle
    bundle.putString("wt", weight);
    // add bundle to the intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), BMI_Result.class);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
      }
    }   
);
```

Second Activity :

```
public class BMI_Result extends Activity 
{
 TextView Weight = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.BMI_TxtVw_wt);
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bmi_result);

    //get the bundle
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    // extract the data
    String weight = bundle.getString("wt");
    Weight.setText(weight);    
 }
```

So please help me for it..

Comment: i can't try the code right now, anyway, check the stack trace of the error in LogCat, you should find out what's wrong (and adjust the formatting of the code you posted if you can)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see you have the following **member** definition in `BMI_Result`:

```
TextView Weight = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.BMI_TxtVw_wt);
```

But you can only call `findViewById` after the class was initialized, since it is a member function of the `View` class, so change this line to:

```
TextView Weight;
```

And add this line to the `onCreate` method right after `setContentView(...)`:

```
Weight = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.BMI_TxtVw_wt);
```

Edit: It said "...right after `super.onCreate(...)`", now it's correct ;)

Comment: hey its working now, Just i Override my onCreate method, and it work. Thnks for ur help....

Answer (score 1):

You should override onCreate()

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

And the token at the end of onCreate is wrong.

Comment: Glad I could help. You appear new to Stack Overflow. Dont forget to accept answers if they answer your question with the check mark by the answer. It helps the reputation of those who offer help and your own reputation. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Context.startActivity(Intent intent) method in your first window/Activity.

Store your data which you want to pass to the second window/Activity in the Intent object, like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("weight", weight);
intent.putExtra("height", height);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

And retrieve them in the second screen/Activity in the onCreate method, like:

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); // This is the intent you previously created.
int weight = intent.getExtra("weight");
int height = intent.getExtra("height");
```

Comment: after writing Context.startActivity(Intent intent) and this.startActivity(intent) its showing error, and I want to call to the next page so I am not getting it.